# Using pwntools process interactive mode to control python3

Tags: python, pwntools

I am trying to use pwntools to control a python3 session. Here is my code:

```
from pwn import process
r = process(['python3'])
r.interactive()
```

However, after I enter `r.interactive()`, when I type into the terminal, the python3 sub-process has strange reactions. At least I do not see my commands echoed back most of the times.

I also tried to call `python3` in a `bash` session, but the same thing happens.

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pwn import process
>>> r = process(['bash'])
[x] Starting local process '/usr/bin/bash'
[+] Starting local process '/usr/bin/bash': pid 119080
>>> r.interactive()
[*] Switching to interactive mode
echo hello 
hello
echo this is bash
this is bash
python3
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)
exit
echo hello
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    echo hello
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this happening? Is it a bug in pwntools, or are there some configurations I overlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the PTY in your shell, so like this:

```py
$ python3
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pwn import *; r = process(['python3'], stdin=PTY, raw=False); r.interactive()
[x] Starting local process '/usr/bin/python3'
[+] Starting local process '/usr/bin/python3': pid 2984281
[*] Switching to interactive mode
Python 3.9.2 (default, Feb 28 2021, 17:03:44) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1+1
1+1
2
>>>
```